# How should I specify changes in MIT licensed code?

Tags: mit

I have MIT licensed code.
There was a bug in this code and I fixed this bug - i.e. changed the originally licensed sources.

Is there any specific format I should use to specify what changes I made to this code?

Are there any good practices/examples of doing this?

Comment: How is the project managed? Is it on Github? Can you fork it, apply your changes and make a pull request?

Answer (score 3):

Please send bugfixes to the current maintainer.

Many maintainers have a FAQ that mentions their preferred format.
For example:

- the "unified diff" format -- the Linux Kernel [a](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SubmittingPatches); [b](http://kniggit.net/ancient-misc/linux-journal/contributing-linux-kernel-diff-patch/)
- the "unified diff" format -- OpenWrt [c](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/patches)
- the "unified diff" format -- Gimp [d](https://www.gimp.org/bugs/howtos/submit-patch.html)
- the "unified diff" format -- FreeBSD [e](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/slow-patch.html)
- the "unified diff" format -- Python [f](http://bugs.python.org/issue1623153)
- etc.

Comment: Hmm... I feel like this doesn't answer the question. It feels like those "link-only" answers - without the links, the answer provides little to no information that is actually helpful. Why don't you quote some one or two of these links, and retain the rest?

Answer (score 3):

A secondary point-
Please provide details of what you've done, and *why*
This is covered in the links above, but nothing is worse than getting a patch through, that changes variable X to variable Y with no explanation.

Whilst you've probably spent time finding and fixing the bug, remember that whoever reviews your patch may well not know anything about it.
Hence, a code lump with minimal or no documentation attached is a massive pain in the neck to deal with.